# JSON conditional writes in Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Using Play! 2.1 Json library, is there a way to write a field to json only if a certain condition is met? For example:

```
case class Foo(id: Int, name: String)
```

I'd like to define a `Writes` that only generates a `name` field if name is not empty. So that:

```
Json.toJson(Foo(1, "Chuck")) //yields {"id":1,"name":"Chuck"}    
Json.toJson(Foo(1, ""))      //yields {"id":1}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to write your own `Writes[T]` class, in this case `Writes[Foo]` see [Scaladoc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Json%24) for reference. Or you can change the String to an `Option[String]` and write one `Writes[Option[String]]` or `Writes[Option[_]]`.

I haven't tried it myself but it's very similar to Spray-json which I have used in the past.

Comment: +1, if a field is optional, it should be made an `Option[_]`.